# child components communications in angularjs 1.5.x

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-components

I have an angularjs component with 2 child components. I want to call a function in `product-list` component when `on-added` output triggers in `new-product` component.

```
<h1>{{vm.store.title}}</h1>
<product-list store-id="vm.storeId"></product-list>
<new-product store-id="vm.store.id" on-added="$ctrl.productAdded()"></new-product>
```

The productAdded method is in `product-list` component and re-initiate the product list.

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: I think that parent component of these two should contain function You want to invoke. What is this function supposed to do ?

Comment: The product-list component get the list of products of a store by getting store-id input. When I add the function in parent component it called but who i reload the list when add a product from new-product component?

Comment: I think product-list should get list of products from parent component, and parent component should append new product to this list. Then Your problem dissapears.

Comment: You can just have a product list component which will take care of displaying the products with custom template if any and let the parent component/controller handle the list manipulations(adding, deleting, updating product list).

Comment: This approach is called one way dataflow. You bubble events up then data goes down through component tree.

Comment: Thanks @KasperZiemianek  for your solutions. But I am looking for a mechanism to child to child components communication.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In this case I think would be better using a common parent component and make the `product-list` a dumb component which receive a list and display it only. So that the parent take care of this management this list and the `product-list` take care of rendering the list. This, allows you to handle the state from a parent component, as `new-product` is dumb as well, it'll emmit changes to the parent and propagate the new list state to the child (a.k.a. `product-list`).

For example, consider using something similar to this raw tree of components:

```
<product-manager store-id="$ctrl.storeId">
    <h1>{{vm.store.title}}</h1>
    <product-list products="vm.store.products"></product-list>
    <new-product on-added="vm.productAdded(product)"></new-product>
</product-manager>
```

Or perhaps:

```
<products-page store="$ctrl.store">
    <h1>{{ $ctrl.store.title }}</h1>
    <product-list products="$ctrl.store.products"></product-list>
    <product-form on-save="$ctrl.productAdded(product)"></product-form>
</products-page>
```

> The previous examples are raw representation of a component tree and its templates, in a real situation you'd have `<products-page store="$ctrl.store"></products-page>` because it's internal nodes would be defined by its template on the component definition.

Comment: Thanks @Lenilson-de-castro for your solution. But I am looking for a mechanism to child to child components communication.

Comment: @MikeAnderson the answer actually is the solution for your scenario. However, if you want to keep them as siblings and keep the comunication somehow with each other, you could use events. For example: `$rootScope.$broadcast('productListUpdated')` on the `new-product` and: `$scope.$on('productListUpdated', this.reloadProductList)` on `product-list`. I think this might help.